# Filter/grok method on logstash

Tags: csv, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

Supposed I have this log file:

```
Jan 1 22:54:17 drop   %LOGSOURCE% >eth1 rule: 7; rule_uid: {C1336766-9489-4049-9817-50584D83A245}; src: 70.77.116.190; dst: %DSTIP%; proto: tcp; product: VPN-1 & FireWall-1; service: 445; s_port: 2612;
Jan 1 22:54:22 drop   %LOGSOURCE% >eth1 rule: 7; rule_uid: {C1336766-9489-4049-9817-50584D83A245}; src: 61.164.41.144; dst: %DSTIP%; proto: udp; product: VPN-1 & FireWall-1; service: 5060; s_port: 5069;
Jan 1 22:54:23 drop   %LOGSOURCE% >eth1 rule: 7; rule_uid: {C1336766-9489-4049-9817-50584D83A245}; src: 69.55.245.136; dst: %DSTIP%; proto: tcp; product: VPN-1 & FireWall-1; service: 445; s_port: 2970;
Jan 1 22:54:41 drop   %LOGSOURCE% >eth1 rule: 7; rule_uid: {C1336766-9489-4049-9817-50584D83A245}; src: 95.104.65.30; dst: %DSTIP%; proto: tcp; product: VPN-1 & FireWall-1; service: 445; s_port: 2565;
Jan 1 22:54:43 drop   %LOGSOURCE% >eth1 rule: 7; rule_uid: {C1336766-9489-4049-9817-50584D83A245}; src: 222.186.24.11; dst: %DSTIP%; proto: tcp; product: VPN-1 & FireWall-1; service: 2967; s_port: 6000;
Jan 1 22:54:54 drop   %LOGSOURCE% >eth1 rule: 7; rule_uid: {C1336766-9489-4049-9817-50584D83A245}; src: 74.204.108.202; dst: %DSTIP%; proto: udp; product: VPN-1 & FireWall-1; service: 137; s_port: 53038;
Jan 1 22:55:10 drop   %LOGSOURCE% >eth1 rule: 7; rule_uid: {C1336766-9489-4049-9817-50584D83A245}; src: 71.111.186.26; dst: %DSTIP%; proto: tcp; product: VPN-1 & FireWall-1; service: 445; s_port: 38548;
Jan 1 23:02:56 accept %LOGSOURCE% >eth1 inzone: External; outzone: Local; rule: 3; rule_uid: {723F81EF-75C9-4CBB-8913-0EBB3686E0F7}; service_id: icmp-proto; ICMP: Echo Request; src: 24.188.22.101; dst: %DSTIP%; proto:
```

What filters/grok method can I implement for them to be separated into different fields? If I were to use semi colon as the separator, it would be different for the last row of data as there are more semi colons than other rows. Should I use a If else statement for it to separate?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a typical use case for [grok](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html) and [kv](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-kv.html) filter.

First use the grok filter to separate your fields. Put the last part (key value pairs) into one field. Use the [grok debugger](http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/) to find the correct pattern. This might be an approach:

```
%{CISCOTIMESTAMP:timestamp} %{WORD:action}%{SPACE}%{DATA:logsource} %{DATA:interface} %{GREEDYDATA:kvpairs}
```

In logstash's config:

```
grok {
    match => [ 'message', '%{CISCOTIMESTAMP:timestamp} %{WORD:action}%{SPACE}%{DATA:logsource} %{DATA:interface} %{GREEDYDATA:kvpairs}' ]
}
```

Afterwards use the kv filter to split the key value pairs. Something like this might work:

```
kv {
    source => "kvpairs" # new field generated by grok before
    field_split => "; " # split fields by semicolon
}
```

Try it and maybe adjust it a little bit and you should be able to parse all log lines correctly.

Comment: I'll try later! Do I have to specify the columns myself after that for the kvpairs?

Comment: No, the kv filter recognizes the columns. Thus, the columns may vary per message.